# Find min value in a CSV and print every row that includes it in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Thanks so much in advance for any help. I'm trying to write a script that will go through a folder of csv files, find the minimum value in the second column and print every row that contains it. The csv files the script looks through looks like this:

```
TPN,12010,on this date,25,0.00005047619239909304377497309619
TPN,12011,on this date,23,0.00003797836224092152019127884704
TPN,12012,on this date,78,0.0001130474103447076420049393022
TPN,12020,on this date,27,0.00005671375308512314236202279053
TPN,12021,on this date,60,0.00009856619048244864701475864425
```

The script looks like this:

```
import csv
import os

folder = '/Users/Documents/Senior/Thesis/Python/TextAnalysis/datedmatchedngrams2/'

identity = []
for filename in os.listdir (folder):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        column = 1               
        datatype = int
        data = (datatype(row[column]) for row in incsv)   
        least_value = min(data)
        print least_value
        for row in incsv:
            if least_value in column[1]:
                identity.append(row)
            else:
                print "No match"
        print identity
```

The error I get is:

```
  File "findfirsttrigram.py", line 12, in <module>
    identity.append("a")
NameError: name 'identity' is not defined
```

I also tried doing it like this:

```
import csv
import os

folder = '/Users/Documents/Senior/Thesis/Python/TextAnalysis/datedmatchedngrams2/'

for filename in os.listdir (folder):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        column = 1               
        datatype = int
        data = (datatype(row[column]) for row in incsv)   
        least_value = min(data)
        print least_value
        for row in incsv:
            if least_value in row:
                print row
            else:
                print "No match"
```

But that didn't work either. It did not give me an error but it also did not print "No match" so I have no idea where to start. Please help!!

Answer (score 4):

You can do somthing like:

```
import csv

# for each_file in os.listdir (folder):    
with open(each_file) as f:
    m=min(int(line[1]) for line in csv.reader(f))
    f.seek(0)
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        if int(line[1])==m:
            print line
```

Comment: Actually dawg, unfortunately this didn't work! It just prints the last line in each csv file.

Comment: It works on your example data if you put in multiple lines with the same min values. Can you post data where it does NOT work?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your minimum value is not found is that you convert your column to an `int` when you are looking for a minimum value, but it still remains a string when you look at it as part of the row you have read. Try changing your code like this:

```
for row in incsv:
    if int(row[column])==least_value:
        print row
    else:
        print "No match"
```

Regarding the other error, inside the `with` clause the global `identity` appears to be not accessible. You can either reintroduce it with `global` or not use `with` clause.

Comment: Thank you and this got me further but kept printing No Match when there was one!

Answer (score 1):

Ashalynd covered why the value testing would fail.  However for the reason that your "No match" statement is never called is because your csv reader can't iterate over the data twice.  Take a simple example like this.

```
with open(filename) as inf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf)
    total_lines = 0
    for line in incsv:
        total_lines += 1
    print total_lines

    total_lines = 0
    for line in incsv:
        total_lines += 1
    print total_lines
```

Assuming there are 999 records it will output the following:

```
999
0
```

That's because at the end of the first iteration the file objects position is at the end.  You need to reset it back to the start of the file to reiterate over the data.  `inf.seek(0)` and the second example should be fine.  Pretty sure this will work.

```
for filename in os.listdir (folder):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        column = 1               
        datatype = int
        #This sets the file's current position to the end
        data = (datatype(row[column]) for row in incsv)   
        least_value = min(data)
        print least_value
        #This resets the file's current position to be read again
        inf.seek(0)
        for row in incsv:
            # Check if the value is the same as properly casted data
            if least_value == datatype(row[column]):
                print row
            else:
                print "No match"
```